# Transparent object not fully transparent

Tags: image, transparency

A few days ago, I watched this Video from "Blender Guru" on Youtube (i´ts about the modern kitchen):https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyXRBu7gn2o. There he showed a trick how to reduce render times, by adding transparent images instead of real trees as trees to the scene. My Question: How did he make their backgroud fully transparent? Always when I import Transparent Images(the background is transparent) i`ts only "half transparent"

[image: half transparent Image]

It also does not change, when I switch between Material-Preview or Rendered Mode:(((
As you can see in the Video which is linked above, Andrew has images where the background is completely transparent, but how does he do that?
(I have exported the image of the tree myself, made sure that the output is PNG, RGBA, and the in the Film-Panel I activadet Transparent)->have I forgotton something? I also tried to render the tree normal(no transparent background) and changed it in GIMP, but that did not help as well. It also doesn`t change when I import the Image instead of "Image-as-plane" as Plane where it is applied to.
Maybe you know an anwser to my question, thanks!!!

PS: I`m from Austria, so I want to apollogise, if my English is not so good, you can always ask quesions If something unclear:)

Comment: Can you show image and material nodes?

Answer (score 1):

When you import the image set the import images as planes to use alpha.
[image]

Or set the material to use the alpha channel in the alpha input of the shader.

[image]